# Kibana visualization without time aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have data with the following format::

```
{
  timestamp: Date,
  x: number
}
```

I want to display these values simply in a line, without any aggregation over `x`, but in Kibana it always requires me to select some kind of aggregation, like average.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create the line-chart that you request, but for Kibana to create an visualization, I'm afraid an aggregation would be necessary.

Kibana basis its visualization on **buckets** (Date, x-axis) and **metrics** (x, y-axis). **Buckets** are aggregations of documents over a specified search (almost 30 aggregation methods)
. **Metrics** are value(s) based on the documents contained in each bucket (almost 20 aggregation methods)
(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html).

However, you could try to create **buckets with 'date_histogram'** for which the **time interval is small** enough so it contain **one document**. Then for the metric aggregation you could select min or max aggregation *(Note: This assumes though that you timestamp is unique for each document)*.

Comment: I'll try it, I'll let you know how it goes